# AWS API Gateway - Conditial Integration Response Formatting?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity, jsonpath

I've configured AWS API Gateway to act as a proxy for a DynamoDB GET HTTP operation.

The following integration request pulls all records where "topic" == 'sensor' via HTTP GET/POST:

```
{
    "TableName": "SensorData",
    "IndexName": "topic-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "topic = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('sensor')"
        }
    }
}
```

This all works great. My issue is in formatting the Integration Response that the AWS API Server exposes to the end client. I have several different topics exposed via the API and would like to format the payloads conditionally via "Mapping Template: application/json", based on payload specifics.

I deployed this script, but my deployed API is now serving blank dictionaries:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  #if("$elem.topic.S" == "sensor_kitchen")
    "comments": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "userId": "$elem.userId.S",
            "topic": "$elem.topic.S",
            "timeStamp": "$elem.timeStamp.S",
            "status": "$elem.status.BOOL"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end
    ]
  #elseif("$elem.topic.S" == "sensor_livingroom")
    "comments": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "userId": "$elem.userId.S",
            "topic": "$elem.topic.S",
            "timeStamp": "$elem.timeStamp.S"
            "status": "$elem.status.BOOL"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    ]
    #elseif("$elem.topic.S" == "sensor_bedroom")
      "comments": [
          #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
          "userId": "$elem.userId.S",
          "topic": "$elem.topic.S",
          "timeStamp": "$elem.timeStamp.S"
          "heart_rate": "elem.heart_rate.S",
          "heart_rate_variability": "$elem.heart_rate_variability.S",
          "measured_signal_strength": "$elem.measured_signal_strength.S"
          }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end
      ]
      #elseif("$elem.topic.S" == "sensor_bathroom")
        "comments": [
            #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "userId": "$elem.userId.S",
            "topic": "$elem.topic.S",
            "timeStamp": "$elem.timeStamp.S",
            "prediction": "$elem.prediction.S"
            }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        ]
      #end
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.